# Render Partial View to Ajax request Zend framework 3

Tags: php, ajax, zend-framework3

I need to know how to send HTML from partial view to Ajax request and Ajax display it in specific div in main page.

The actual issue that i had profile page that contain 2 Div's, one of them display some links. When i click on any link, new data will appear related to that link in the second div in page (dynamic page content).

So now i need to load new html that i saved in another and display it with JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the solution that helps me

```
// get view model which need to loaded
 $htmlView = new ViewModel();
 $htmlOutput = $htmlView
      ->setTerminal(true)
      ->setTemplate(templateName)
      ->setVariable($key, $value);
return $htmlOutput;
```

also make ajax dataType as html

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: requestedUrl,
            data: {},
            dataType : "html",
            success: function(data) {
                $('.divId').html(data');
            },
            error: function(error) {},
            complete: function() {}
        });
```